# How could I convert FFT bytes to a wav file

Tags: android, fft

I am using `onFftDataCapture` to capture the FFT data of Android, and I want to store the data to a MP3 file or wav file. Is there any function to do that? with IDFT?

Comment: yes when you feed the frequency domain data ( output from FFT call ) into an inverse fft call it will be raw audio in PCM format which is the curve in time domain which can be saved as wave once this pcm audio is sent into some wav library ... similar for mp3 ... what have you tried ?

Comment: @ScottStensland I am still trying to convert data, it is a little hard for me.